# How to retrieve workflows associated to an Object , using metadata API?

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, workflow, metadata-api, metadata

I want to search for all the workflows associated with an object.
can someone please help me with this.

**How this can be done using metadataservice.cls that has been generated using WSDL ?**

**Which services need to be call to get the details ?**

**Is there any documentation where i can get the functionality of all the services of salesforce WSDLs ?**

Thanks

Comment: Metadata API developers guide?

Comment: I am a bit confused about which service should be used and how should it be used ?
I am new to APEX,
I will be obliged if you can provide some code snippet or service name(method)
that should be used for this requirement. 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I retrieve all workflowrule for Opportunity by using Developer Console> Query Editor.Example of query is like below

> select id,Name from WorkflowRule Where TableEnumOrId='Opportunity'

Make sure you click at Use Tooling API before Execute the query.
[image]

Comment: Getting an error `sObject type 'WorkflowRule' is not supported.`

Comment: if you not check on Use Tooling API , it will prompt the error.Please check Use Tooling API as picture above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SpringTool](https://springfive.com/springtool-offer/) to retrieve all the workflows and the associated actions for a given object or even a list of objects.
Even the free version of SpringTool allows you to do so (Menu "Audit" > "Configuration Workbook").
After connecting to your org, you can select the object(s) for which you want to get the list of workflow and workflow actions.
It will generate an Excel file with one tab per object with all the details. It's free: give it a try and let me know!